# Очистить список от текстовых элементов и тегов

Tags: python, list

```
Существует список:

    li = [<a href="https://data.binance.vision/data/spot/daily/klines/BNBBTC/5m/BNBBTC-5m-2021-03-08.zip">BNBBTC-5m-2021-03-08.zip</a>,
# <a href="https://data.binance.vision/data/spot/daily/klines/BNBBTC/5m/BNBBTC-5m-2021-03-07.zip">BNBBTC-5m-2021-03-07.zip</a>,
# a href="https://data.binance.vision/data/spot/daily/klines/BNBBTC/5m/BNBBTC-5m-2021-03-03.zip">BNBBTC-5m-2021-03-03.zip</a>]
```

Список переполнен лишними тегами,и строками а нужны только список с содержимым в кавычках:

```
    li = ["https://data.binance.vision/data/spot/daily/klines/BNBBTC/5m/BNBBTC-5m-2021-03-08.zip",
"https://data.binance.vision/data/spot/daily/klines/BNBBTC/5m/BNBBTC-5m-2021-03-07.zip",
"https://data.binance.vision/data/spot/daily/klines/BNBBTC/5m/BNBBTC-5m-2021-03-03.zip"]
```

Как это сделать, т.е. как очистить список от других тэгов или строк и сделать второй список?

Comment: На будущее - вставляйте код правильно, пожалуйста. Этот я поправил сейчас.

Comment: если элементы списка это строки, то извлечь из них ссылки можно с помощью регулярного выражения

Comment: можете попробывать BeautifulSoup